# Cant Access System.Web for Silverlight Application

Tags: .net, silverlight

Im writing a simple Silverlight Application (Simple Silverlight Video Player) not hosted on IIS and Im using VS Express 2013 and C#.

Im trying to include the System.Web namespace.

`using System.Web;`

However the IDE will not resolve this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight uses a cut-down version of the .NET framework so you cannot use all the classes and namespaces that exist in the full version. You can check the list of what's included in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on MSDN.

`System.Web` is not included.

Comment: Thanks, I will bookmark this page, btw, any idea how I could map the path to the `MapPath("/ClientBin");` since this namespace is not available ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but `MapPath` returns the path on the server whereas the Silverlight code runs on the client machine and has no access to the server. I'm not sure what happens if you don't host it in IIS.

Comment: ok I think I know now, I should send the full http path of my file. Thanks for your help